# Error Setting Up Player: Invalid License Key cycle

Tags: javascript, windows-10, jwplayer, license-key, jwplayer7

I haven't been able to play JavaScript videos since I bought my PC a few months ago. I keep getting that frustrating "Error Setting Up Player: Invalid License Key" error pop up over my videos. I've tried 4 browsers (Chrome, Canary, Edge, & IE), cleared the cache and everything and no luck. Can't get Chrome to update all its extensions but the ones on Canary are up to date. The Flash player is up to date too. My computer time is fine too since I know people have tried that to fix this issue.

I downloaded the folder of the latest jwplayer and can't do anything with the files.

Has anyone else had this problem? Please help! I need to be open my medical licensing exam videos.

Thanks.

Comment: This seems like something you need to contact their support for.

Comment: I've tried several times and get no response possibly because I don't have a premium account.

Comment: Do you have a sample page? Does this error show in other computers? It does not seems a browser issue, but a server problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your machine's time is probably not correct. Else, you're using the wrong license key.

Answer (score 0):

just clear the browsing history, cache etc and reload the page where you have the video....worked for me!!!